# priority roads data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation, traffic

Is there any data source for priority roads(: roads which are indicated to have priority with a traffic sign on site, overriding the 'priority to the right' rule) excluding OpenStreetMap?

The bigger the coverage, the better.

Sadly, OSM almost only contains this tag in some European instances, having a total of 10k OSM ways tagged as priority roads worldwide.
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:priority_road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work in this field and this data for any large geography is not available from an open source that I know of. I know at least three private companies that hold such data.

Comment: Thanks, I realised that priority roads are majorly at least tertiary roads by road type, and fortunately that information is good enough for me to work with